# How to display the placeholder text as "Write your comment here..." in inputtextarea, but all in capital letters

Tags: visualforce

[image: placeholder text]

Need to display the text as "Write your comment here...", but here by default it is displayed as the above image.

Code :

```
<apex:inputTextarea   placeholder="Write your comment here..."/>
```

Comment: if you update your post with what you have tried, it will be easier to help and propose a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mention docuType as 'Html-5.0' in apex page.
You can use the [pass through](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_html_features_pass_through_attributes.htm) attributes for this:

```
<apex:inputTextarea   html-placeholder="Write your comment here..."/>
```

The behavior of HTML5 features is determined by the **user’s browser**, not **Visualforce**, and varies considerably from browser to browser.

Comment: I have mentioned docType="html-5.0" in the page tag and <apex:inputTextarea id="abccmt"  html-placeholder="Write your comment here..."/>  But still capital letters are displayed, i have tried inserting the same text from label as well - still no use.

Comment: @B1sfdc Its was working perfectly for me as i mention "Write your comment here..." in text area.

Comment: @B1sfdc What is the exact code you are using for inputTextArea? Did you trace in browser what went wrong ?

Comment: I have tried even this html tag <textarea id="abccmt"  type="text" placeholder="{!$Label.AYKE_FAQ_Placeholder}" ></textarea> Please let me know what could be the possibilities

Comment: @B1sfdc Along with html-placeholder, maybe use some [CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180140/make-input-value-uppercase-in-css-without-affecting-the-placeholder).